# Expressjs rest api how to deal with chaining functionality

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, router

I am building a restful API using express, mongoose and mongodb. It works all fine but I have a question about how to deal with requests that contain more functionality than just one find, delete or update in the database. My user model looks as follows:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  emailaddress: {type: String, unique: true},
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  password: String,
  friends: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, unique: true}]
});
```

As you can see is the friends array just an array of ObjectIds. These ObjectIds refer to specific users in the database. If I want to retrieve an array of a user's friends I now have to look up the user that makes the request, then find all the users that have the same id as in the friends array.

Now it looks like this:

```
methods.get_friends = function(req, res) {
  //find user.
   User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, user, next) {

    if(err) next(err);
    if(user) {
      console.log(user);

      //find friends
      User.find({_id: {$in: user.friends}}, {password: 0}).exec(function (err,
        friends, next) {
        if(err) next(err);
        if(friends) {

          res.send(friends);
        };
      });
    }
```

Would it be possible to seperate the lookup of the user in a certain method and chain the methods? I saw something about middleware chaining i.e. `app.get('/friends', getUser, getFriend)`but would that mean that I have to alter the req object in my middleware (getUser) method and then pass it on? How would you solve this issue? Would you perhaps change the mongoose model and save all friend data (means that it could become outdated) or would you create a method getUser that returns a promise on which you would collect the friend data?

I will be grateful for all the help I can get!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would probably use Mongoose's [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) ability, which is pretty similar to your current schema already. Middleware (at least in the way you're describing) is an Express construct that doesn't directly make sense to apply on top of Mongoose IMO.

Comment: Thank you Robert, I used the populate ability. Could you create an answer with the information of your comment, then I can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose has a feature called [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) which exists to help in these kinds of situations. Basically, Mongoose will perform the extra query/queries that are required to load the `friends` documents from the database:

```
User.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
    .populate('friends')
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      ...
    });
```

This will load any related friends into `user.friends` (as an array).

If you want to add additional constraints (in your example, `password : 0`), you can do that too:

```
User.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
    .populate({
      path  : 'friends'
      match : { password : 0 },
    })
    .exec(function(err, user) {
      ...
    });
```

See also [this documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate).

Comment: almost exactly what I did to solve this issue. Thank you!